# Lucene IndexSearcher causing OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, lucene.net

This is my code to search the Lucene index,

```
String DocPath=@"c:\Test1.txt";
if (File.Exists(DocPath))
{
    StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(DocPath);

    StringBuilder Content = new StringBuilder();
    Content.Append(Reader.ReadToEnd());

    if (Content.ToString().Trim() != "")
    {
        FSDirectory Direc = FSDirectory.Open(new DirectoryInfo(IndexDir));
        IndexReader Reader = IndexReader.Open(Direc, true);
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(Reader);
        QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Content", new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, new FileInfo(Application.StartupPath + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "noise.dat")));
        BooleanQuery.MaxClauseCount = Convert.ToInt32(Content.ToString().Length);
        Query query = parser.Parse(QueryParser.Escape(Content.ToString().ToLower()));
        TopDocs docs = searcher.Search(query, Reader.maxDoc);
    }
}
```

In this code I am opening one text file of 15MB and giving it to the index searcher. The search takes very long time and apparently throws an `OutOfMemoryException`. It even takes time to parse the query. Index size is around 16K docs.

Comment: are you trying to find documents that are exactly the same as Test1.txt?

Comment: yes i am trying to find documents that are same as test1

Comment: If you're trying to find the exact match, I don't think you need to use the analyzer on that field. That might drastically reduce the size of your query. It could be however, that a 15MB query is simply too large.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you change your approach. With the document, store an additional field that contains the hash of the file, like a MD5 hash for example.

Use your input to compute it's hash and issue a Query for that hash, and compare the matching documents with your input for equality.

It will be a lot more robust, and will probably be more performant too.

Comment: I did use your approach,But it returns 0 docs.But i guess this method will return only docs which are 100% matching..bcoz i am storing HASH value and query on hash value,so it will return 0 docs bcoz on mdhash value is matched